# Capture clicked links in a UIWebView using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, rx-swift, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm starting to use RxSwift at work and I'm on a project right now where I need to capture clicked links in a web view.
But I can’t get this method :
`webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool`
from the UIWebViewDelegate to work. It's never called no matter what I do.

I tried to use the DelegateProxy thing but I think I don’t get it...
I’m also trying to figure out what would be a more “Reactive” way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using some of the [Reactive Properties](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIWebView%2BRx.swift#L37), your delegate is already "taken over" by RxSwift/RxCocoa. If you want to use your delegate "as usual" alongside RxSwift you'll need to set a the delegate proxy.

e.g.

```swift
webView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong: it was my implementation of the method that returned false when it was first called by the web view... I just didn't knew that it was called when calling programmatically...